# Unable to add enumerate in footnote. Showing errors. I am attaching the photo for better understanding

Tags: beamer, footnotes, enumerate, enumitem

[image: I need the format mentioned below in the copy but I am unable to do it.]

I am attaching the footnote code here

```
{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{\hspace{-16.5pt}{\textbf{\framebox[1.3cm]{Pioneer :}}}}}
{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{\hspace{-16.5pt}{\textbf{\framebox[1.3cm]{Recent :}} \begin{enumerate}
                \item E. T.H. S. , in Proceedings of the    51st Annual         \end{enumerate} 
            }}}
```

No citation is required no footmark required in frame. just footnotes in the below mentioned format

Comment: it is virtually impossible to understand what the image is showing. There is no need to show a redacted image make a small but complete document with dummy text that shows the problem so people can see the issue and test answers. (`let\thefootnote\relax` will break the footnote code I would expect but I can not guess the intention of the code to suggest what to change)

Comment: I want to arrange the footnote as mentioned in the writings in latex

Comment: The image shows something that looks like `beamer`. Do you really need a footnote? Writing at the bottom of the slide wouldn't suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{\hspace{-16.5pt}{\textbf{\framebox[1.3cm]{Pioneer :}}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item E. T.H. S. , in Proceedings of the    51st Annual
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \end{enumerate}    
}}}    

{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{\hspace{-16.5pt}{\textbf{\framebox[1.3cm]{Recent :}}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item E. T.H. S. , in Proceedings of the    51st Annual
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \end{enumerate}    
}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]